# To test pundit, its necessary to log in at the app first?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

I am using pundit gem to authorize in my system app. before to implement pundit I had my endpoint index like this:

```rb
    def index
        @cars = Car.all
        render json: @cars
    end
```

worked ok, but now with pundit, i made a change like this

```rb
    def index
        @cars = Car.all
        authorize @cars
    end
```

Now I am getting this error:

> **current_user must be defined before the impersonates method**

Answer (score 0):

Pundit works a little differently for the *index* route. typically you want to do exactly what you where trying `authorize @post` but we only pass *one record*.

So for you:

```rb
# posts_controller.rb
def index
  @posts = policy_scope(Post)
end
```

this hits the following in pundit:

```rb
# app/policies/post_policy.rb
# [...]
class Scope < Scope
  def resolve
    scope.all # If users can see all posts
    # scope.where(user: user) # If users can only see their posts
    # scope.where("name LIKE 't%'") # If users can only see posts starting with `t`
    # ...
  end
end
```

As for your error related to the current_user, is that coming from pundit? In pundit itself your current_user (from devise for example) will be just **user**, such that you can check `record.user == user`.